# List comprehension with class attributes

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to use class attributes to make a single list of all attributes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: int
    b: int

data = [
    Foo(1,2),
    Foo(3,4)
]
print([[foo.a, foo.b] for foo in data])
```

But the result is a list of lists of attributes. How can I have a single list containing all attributes `[1,2,3,4]` instead of `[[1,2],[3,4]]`?

Comment: `sum([[foo.a, foo.b] for foo in data],[])`?

Comment: Exactly something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the intermediate list

```
In [6]: import itertools

In [7]: print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[foo.a, foo.b] for foo in data])))                                                                                                                               
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce 
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
  a: int
  b: int

data = [
  Foo(1,2),
  Foo(3,4)
]

result = [[foo.a, foo.b] for foo in data]
print(reduce(list.__add__, result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested list comprehension

```
[x for x in [foo.a, foo.b] for foo in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
print([value for foo in data for attr, value in foo.__dict__.items()])
```

It's basically doing two for loops, the same as doing:

```
for foo in data:
    for attr, value in foo.__dict__.items():
        print(value)
```